# What is the best design pattern for asynchronous message passing in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, chrome

I have a background script that is responsible for getting and setting data to a `localStorage` database. My content scripts must communicate with the background script to send and receive data.

Right now I send a JSON object that contains the command and the data to a function. So if I'm trying to add an object to the database I'll create JSON that has a `command` attribute that is `addObject` and another object that is the data. Once this is completed the background scripts sends a response back stating that it was successful.

Another use case of the function would be to ask for data in which case it would send an object back rather than a success/fail.

The code gets kind of *hacky* once I start trying to retrieve the returned object from the background script.

It seems like there is probably a simple design problem to follow here that I'm not familiar with. Some people have suggested future/promise design problems but I haven't found a very good example.

Content Script

```
function sendCommand(cmdJson){
chrome.extension.sendRequest(cmdJson, function(response){
    //figure out what to do with response
});
}
```

Background script

```
if (request.command == "addObject"){
  db[request.id]= JSON.stringify(request.data); 
    sendResponse("success");
}
else if(request.command == "getKeystroke"){
  var keystroke = db[request.id];
  sendResponse(keystroke);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure about which pattern you will call it. I would say following looks like Command pattern, I would do this..

```
var commands = {
         "addObject":function(request){/*Do something, send response etc*/},
         "getKeystroke":function(request){/*Do something, send response etc*/},
}
```

And in request handler

```
var requestHandler = function(request) {
      commands[request.command](request);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I ended up doing.